# document.cookie is empty when it is in the response header

Tags: javascript, c#, reactjs, asp.net-core

I am working on a .net core api project and I am trying to set a simple cookie in the response like this:

```
HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("user", "test", new CookieOptions() { Path = "/", Domain = "", IsEssential = true });
```

I can see the cookie in the response header in Safari, but not in Chrome.
The problem more specifically is that even though I see the cookie in the header, document.cookie is always an empty string.  I know that HTTPOnly disallows access to the cookie from the browser, but it is defaulted to false in my case.

I am running this from a react app that is hosted at localhost:3000 and it is connecting to an api at localhost:5001.  I don't think that is relevant since the cookie is set in the header anyways.  BTW, I have deployed this to a site so it was all under the same domain, but it doesn't seem to matter.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Chrome doesn't allow setting cookies on an empty domain. Try using `Domain = null`.

The full example:

```
HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("user", "test", new CookieOptions() { Path = "/", Domain = null, IsEssential = true });
```